# Parse JSON string in AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

In controler i have database results with JSON encode, i echo variable from controller , and wanna pass it into ajax succes part. I it posible to parse results by parse function, i how to display db results in ajax success part???

controler

```
 <?php 
 $this->db->limit($l, $rpp);
 $row = $this->db->get('pages');
 echo json_encode($row);
```

ajax

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo site_url('search/ajax')?>",
    data: { 'rpp' : rpp , 'last' : last, 'pn' : pn},
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(msg){
      // var json = msg;
      var obj = JSON.parse(msg);
      ...
    }
});
```

i get here some kind of error is it posible to get data in this way????

Comment: It would be helpful if you could add the error message you're getting.

Comment: "some kind of error" is not a very helpful error message.

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

Comment: ,maybe a typo `('search/ajax')?>",` missing `;`

Comment: First of all use proper header on php side: `header('Content-type: application/json')`, this way you can get rid of parsing string to object on jQuery side, and paste error from console please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `dataType: "text"` to `dataType: "json"` and echo ONLY JSON string (otherwise it will throw error):

```
 <?php

 $array = ['name' => 'Jogn', 'age' => 20];
 echo json_encode($array);
```

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(msg); how to get obj results

Comment: @ZeljkoKovacevic Why use explicit JSON parsing, when passing `dataType: "json"` will parse response automatically?

Comment: ok how to display result on other side i used if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
foreach($query->result() as $row) {
    $data[$row->id] = $row->id;
    }
}
$json = json_encode($data);
echo $json;

Answer (score 0):

Check whether the json data that is returning is in proper json format or not and also try dataType: "json" and jQuery.parseJSON(msg); to parse json in your ajax request.